# Retrieving facebook profile ID from image url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given the url of a facebook-hosted image, which looks something like,

```
https://scontent-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t1.0-9/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_n.jpg
```

how can I get the Graph API Photo ID of the image?

I tried using the second number in the image filename as the photoid, but this no longer seems to work. Has facebook changed the URL format, and if so, how?

Comment: Where do you get this filename from?

Comment: The url of the image ("XXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXX_n.jpg")

Comment: Yep, but where do you get the url from?

Comment: You can't. The numbers don't mean anything